# php apache file ownership and creation problem

Tags: php, apache, permissions, chmod, ownership

I am trying to do a really basic rename of a file to another name in my code. However there seems to be some ownership/permissions problem that is stopping this working correctly.

This is my (simplified) code:

```
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$St_Num = '7940';
$Co_Code = 'RDCO2';

rename("$St_Num-$Co_Code-1.jpg", "$St_Num-$Co_Code-4.jpg");
```

These are my permissions of the files I am trying to change:

Code:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache dev   4065 Oct 22 17:57 7940-RDCO2-3.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache dev   4276 Oct 28 09:39 7940-RDCO2-2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache dev   4336 Oct 28 09:39 7940-RDCO2-1.jpg
```

This code was working, and it seemed to work when apache was the *creator* of the file. However, when I changed the ownership to 'apache' it stopped working. Does PHP/Apache have a concept of knowing who the creator of a file was? Would this stop a rename() from working?

I'm stumped with this one now - any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Picco

Comment: For renaming the files, the permissions to look at are those from the containing directory. Please show us the `ls -ld .` information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do `chmod(0666)` [on the server] to give all users (including apache) write rights

Comment: @Cristina , yes it is but i see no other solution for what the OP wants to do

Comment: Apache suexec would take care of this without needing to grant global rights.

Comment: A chmod 666 on the server doesn't seem to have any effect. Apache doesn't need to be the owner of the file, i'm just looking for a way to allow the apache user to be able to rename the files.

Comment: I should also add that i *know* this isn't a bug in the code as I have seen it working. The problem is I just don't know the permissions required that will allow this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set read-write ownership for that specific directory to `public-www`.